# Cordova Android keep phone from locking

Tags: android, cordova, power-management, crosswalk

Our game is using cordova running in fullscreen mode and on android the phone locks while the game is in the foreground. The 'recent apps' android button doesn't work and users to exit have to press home > unlock phone, only then the recent apps works.

Tried so far Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin and PowerManagement plugin but nothing seems to work.

During multiplayer game we have background mode plugin running. Still the phone locks before the background mode was ever called.

Another thing to mention is that the game is using crosswalk.